# Struggle with string formatting pandas date

Tags: pandas

I have the following `stringy` : `2017-12-03`

I am looking forward to turn the `str` into `to_datetime`, add a `BDay` and change the format of such date.

what i tried was :

```
import datetime as dt
from pandas.tseries.offsets import BDay

valor_nuevo=(pd.to_datetime(stringy,'%Y-%m-%d') + BDay(1)).strftime('%d/%m/%Y')
```

And outputs as error  an `AssertionError`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need define parameter `format` or omit it in [`to_datetime`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.to_datetime.html):

```
valor_nuevo = (pd.to_datetime(stringy,format='%Y-%m-%d') + BDay(1)).strftime('%d/%m/%Y')

valor_nuevo = (pd.to_datetime(stringy) + BDay(1)).strftime('%d/%m/%Y')
```

---

```
print (valor_nuevo)
04/12/2017
```